# CoreData Edit one attribute in One to Many relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am new to CoreData and been looking to all the books and examples but none of them really tell me how to do this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Basically, I have 2 Entities in one to Many relation. [other relationships are not important in this case]

The relationship and entities:

[image]

Now I can get All the MedicalCondition Entity based on given Profile Entity using NSFetchRequest

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MedicalCondition" inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"condition" ascending:YES]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"MedicalToProfile = %@", myProfile];
//request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                   initWithFetchRequest:request
                                   managedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext
                                   sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                   cacheName:nil];

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [frc performFetch:&error];
NSArray *fetchedObjectsFromCore;
[request release];
if (success) {
    fetchedObjectsFromCore = [frc fetchedObjects];
}
```

This is ok. Now the problem comes in when I want to update one particular entry. I am not sure how to do it. I can add more MedicalCondition object just fine. But  when it comes to edit, I am not sure.

The only way I cant think of is to have "ID" attribute in entity. I think there must be a better solution than this. Please help ! Thankz so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankz again Anurag. 
I kindna got it working.

this is how I did it

```
NSSet *newMedical = myProfile.ProfileToMedical;
NSMutableArray *arrayMedical = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[newMedical allObjects]];

MedicalCondition *c = [arrayMedical objectAtIndex:1];
c.condition = @"Amazing";
```

And It update the right place :)

But now when I call again

```
NSSet *details = myProfile.ProfileToMedical;

NSMutableArray *arrayDetail = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[details allObjects]];
```

The return NSSet is show the updated condition to be at other index. I understand that is because myProfile.ProfileToMedical is unsorted? so I must always sort the array first before I view/edit attribute to ensure the consistency?

Thankz again

Comment: Yes, if ordering is important, then don't directly access them as a NSSet. Create a fetch request, which defines the sort criteria.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Core Data object from a valid context, then editing it is very easy. Modify the object data, then save its context. Let's say you have a `MedicalCondition` object that you got hands on somehow.

```
MedicalCondition *condition;
// modify a field
condition.date = [NSDate date];

// save
NSError *error;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Also if you have a given `Profile` object, you can get all associated `MedicalCondition` objects directly without having to perform a fetch as long as you do not care about order.

```
Profile *someonesProfile = ...;
someonesProfile.conditions

// and access a profile from a given MedicalCondition since
// it seems to be a bi-directional relationship.

MedicalCondition *someCondition = ...;
someCondition.profile.dateofbirth;
```

You should give more meaningful names to the relationships instead of `MedicalToProfile`, `ProfileToMedication`, etc. For example, instead of `ProfileToMedical`, maybe use:

```
medicalConditions
```

which is semantically nicer, and reads better in code:

```
someonesProfile.medicalConditions
```

Comment: Thankz Anurag for your quick reply,

Comment: you're welcome. i hope this was helpful, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I am sorry about the naming, I'll update it as soon as I fix this problem. I still not able to update one entry of the medicalCondition. How can I update the right MedicalCondition Entry? for example I have 5 entry of the MedicalCondition.condition say 'a,b,c,d,e' and I want to change 'b' to 'z'. How would I go about doing that?Thankz again

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Are there 5 MedicalCondition objects? and you want to the change the value of the second one from "b" to "z"?

Comment: Yes there are 5 medicalCondition objects that relate to a specific Profile objects and I want to the change the value[condition attribue] of the second one from "b" to "z".

Comment: Assuming `medicalConditions` is an array, you could do: `MedicalCondition *c = [medicalConditions objectAtIndex:1]; c.condition = @"z";`